# Simplicial set of a loop

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory

We can say that simplicial set is a functor $K: \Delta^{op} \rightarrow Sets$, here morphisms of $\Delta$ are all non-strictly increasing maps from $[0] \rightarrow [1] = \{0, 1\}$. So there are two morphisms of $\Delta^{op}$, one $0 \rightarrow 0$ in $\Delta$ is a map from every edge to its target in $\Delta^{op}$, and $0 \rightarrow 1$ is a map from every edge to its source.

Now, consider a loop with two vertices and two oriented edges which form a circle. $K_0 = K([0])$ is set of two vertices and $K_1 = K([1])$ is set of two edges. And we can construct two morphisms from every edge to either its source or its target. So a map from $K_1 \rightarrow K_0$ as a set map is well-defined.

But what about a loop which only has one vertex and one edge? How can we construct a non-strictly increasing map from $[0] \rightarrow [1]$ which induce a category of this loop?

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one element in $K_1$, then it's in the image of the degeneracy map $K_0 \to K_1,$ so this is not a circle, but a point. Note that the definition of a simplicial set implies having degeneracy maps - $\Delta$ has a map $[1] \to [0]$.

However, if you want your $\Delta$ not to have degeneracies, what you get is a [delta-set](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semi-simplicial+set). Geometric realization of a one-point delta-set will indeed be a circle - you take an interval and a point, and then glue the edges of the interval to this point. And now you don't collapse this as the degeneracy map prescribes in the case of simplicial sets. (A higher-brow to say that is to note that a realization of such a delta-set = fat geometric realization of the corresponding simplicial set = $\operatorname{hocolim}(\{*\} \rightrightarrows \{*\}) = S^1).$

Comment: So a loop which has only one vertex and one edge is not a simplicial set, but a delta set, right?

Comment: @threeautumn I am not sure I get the question. "loop" is not a conventional mathematical term. If you want to speak about Ssets, you speak about Ssets. Instead, you may want to consider delta sets or whatever, depending on your aim.

Comment: here by "loop" I mean a graph, with a vertex and an edge which is a loop from this vertex to itself.

Comment: The shape of the graph is opposite to the shape of the domain category.